# When I run code to post blog i get error: Proxy Authentication required

Tags: wordpress, authentication, proxy

i am writing code in vb to post blog to wordpress.

here is the code

```
Imports CookComputing.XmlRpc

Public Structure blogInfo
    Public title As String
    Public description As String
End Structure





Public Class Form1
  Public Interface IgetCatList
        <CookComputing.XmlRpc.XmlRpcMethod("metaWeblog.newPost")> _
        Function NewPage(ByVal blogId As String, ByVal strUserName As String, ByVal strPassword As String, ByVal content As blogInfo, ByVal publish As Integer) As String
    End Interface

    Private Sub Button1_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click



        Dim categories As IgetCatList
        Dim clientprotocol As XmlRpcClientProtocol
        Dim txt As String

        Dim newBlogPost As blogInfo
        newBlogPost.title = TextBox1.Text
        newBlogPost.description = TextBox2.Text


        categories = CType(XmlRpcProxyGen.Create(GetType(IgetCatList)), IgetCatList)
        clientprotocol = CType(categories, XmlRpcClientProtocol)
        clientprotocol.Url = "http://wordpress.com/#quickpress"  'i am not sure if this is the correct url




         Dim id = categories.NewPage("1", "xxxxxx", "xxxxxxx", newBlogPost, 1)

        MsgBox("Posted to Blog successfullly! Post ID : " + id)
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        TextBox2.Text = ""

    End Sub
End Class
```

When i run this code i get error:Proxy Authentication Required (The ISA Server Requires authorization to fulfill the request Access to web proxy filter is denied)

can anyone please help me resolve thisproblem.
Thnaks

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what the crud I am doing, but I am using similar code like above only in c#.  I'm actually trying to figure out how to make the categories work.  The one thing I do know is the clientprotocol.url should be in this format:

http://yourblog.wordpress.com/xmlrpc.php

I imagine from the date of your post you probably have figured this out by now.